# .ASP.NET Core only run policy handler when policy exists on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm creating a custom authorization policy handler to protect some of my routes. I'm using the `[Authorize]` filter on most of my controllers, however, I want **some** of them to use `[Authorize(Policy="IsVerified")]` so that it'll only allow access if the `IsVerified` claim exists.

My problem is that I've created my handler, but it's being run on every route that has the `[Authorize]` filter, not just the ones the have the `[Authorize(Policy="IsVerified"]`. Is it possible to only have the handler run where that policy exists?

**Here is my custom handler:**

```
public class UserVerifiedHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserVerifiedRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserVerifiedRequirement requirement)
    {
        bool isVerified = Convert.ToBoolean(context.User.FindFirst("UserIsVerified").Value);

        if (isVerified)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Fail();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**Here is how I'm registering it in my Startup.cs**

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserVerifiedHandler>();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("UserIsVerified",
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserVerifiedRequirement(true)));
});
```

**Example Usage**

```
[Authorize(Policy="UserIsVerified")
public IActionResult RouteToOnlyAllowAuthorizedAndVerified() {
    //Access here only if claim is true
}

[Authorize]
public IActionResult RouteToAllowAuthorized() {
    //Access here regardless if claim true or false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a mistake on my end, false alarm. It's working as intended, I just had a controller method being called in the background that already had the policy attached (added earlier for testing purposes and forgot to remove). So it was getting called and making it seem like the handler was being executed when it wasn't supposed to.